# Picky host (lock?)

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

I believe my problem can be considered regardless of used language but, to have some 'anchor', I'll describe it using the Java language.

Let's consider the following scenario:
I have a class **PickyHost** extending Thread and an instance of it, **pickyHostInst** running.
That class might look like this:

```
class PickyHost extends Thread {
    private ArrayList<Guest> guests;
    public void enter(Guest g) {
        // deal with g
    }
    private void pickGuests() {
        // ...
    }
    public void run() {
        // listen indefinitely
    }
}
```

Moreover, in the background, I have many **Guest** instances running (they also extend **Thread** class) and once in a while, some **guest** wants to invoke **enter** method on **pickyHostInst** with an argument **g** being itself.
Now, I want **PickyHost** to be picky in the following sense:

Immediately after someone invokes **enter** method, it puts **g** at the end of **guests** list and forces **g** to wait for notification. Also (I think here lies the crux of the matter) it goes itself for a 5 seconds sleep and somehow allows (during these 5 seconds) other guests to invoke **enter** method (if so happens, then it forgets about how long it had to sleep and resets its alarm clock to sleep exactly 5 seconds again) - I'll call it a *sensitive sleep*.

As you can see, the total amount of time **pickyHostInst** sleeps can be huge if many guests arrive - like: A arrives, then after 4 seconds B arrives, then after another 4 seconds C arrives and so on. However, suppose there's been created a chain A, B, ..., G of guests and from the moment of arrival of G till 5 seconds later, no-one arrived.
Then I want **pickyHostInst** to invoke **pickGuests** method which, using some algorithm, determines a **subset** S of {A, B, ..., G} of guests to notify that they can stop waiting and carry on doing what they normally do and moreover removes elements of S from **guests** list. Method **pickGuests** can take some time to accomplish and in the meantime some guest H might have arrived and invoked **enter** - then **enter** should proceed normally but **pickGuests** should ignore H and to the end of its last invocation deal with {A, B, ..., G} - not with {A, B, ..., G, H}.
After finishing **pickGuests**, **pickyHostInst** should (here I have 2 ideas - implementing any of them will make me happy :))
either

1. fall again into 5 seconds of *sensitive sleep* after which, if no guest after H arrived, invoke **pickGuests** again, or
2. simultaneously serves guests via **enter** method as usual but invokes **pickGuests** only after
   max("a moment when last guest from S (from the last invocation) notifies **pickyHostInst** (like: the last "Thank you, Mr Host" from among S)", "a moment 5 seconds after the last (newest) guest invoked **enter**").

Finally, after a long introduction, my question - which tools do I need to accomplish such task? I'm unfortunately a bit lost among the richness of various locks and multithreading/locking mechanisms and can't discern which one fits to my problem (or which ones, combined somehow).

I'll greatly appreciate some code-sketches that would put me on the right track.

Comment: tl;dr, and **all** this **bold** everywhere **makes** it difficult to **make** sense **of**.

Comment: I would try to just use sleep, wait, notify, notifyAll. I doubt that in this task I would run into something which I cannot implement by using them. Have you run into anything particular where you got stuck?

Comment: @MikeW - I thought that distinguishing entities living in the program could help to comprehend my rather long message. Might have been wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `java.util.Timer` object, which can be reset in the `enter` method. The timer task will run in its own thread and do the picking for you if it is not canceled before hand.

Note that the `enter` method will be running on one of the many `Guest` threads. This means that it should probably synchronized. The easiest way to do this is is to add the `synchronized` keyword to the method declaration in Java: `public synchronized void enter(Guest g)`. This will ensure that only one guest can enter at a time. You can put the timer cancel/restart code in here.

The way `java.util.Timer` works it through the abstract `java.util.TimerTask` class. This is a type of `Runnable` that also has a method to cancel the task. My recommendation is to schedule a task that will pick guests after a 5000ms interval whenever a guest enters. If a task from the previous guest is running, cancel it first.

The `enter` method should acquire the guest's lock (using a synchronized block) and have the guest wait. The picking should call the `notify()` method on the guests you select. This will allow them to continue executing.

When you remove selected guests from your queue, be aware of the fact that Java collections are not thread-safe by default. You will have to use an external lock to ensure that no-one else is modifying your list when you add and remove guests. The `Collections.synchronizedList(List)` method provides a handy way to do this.

Here is a list of links that discuss the topics I have mentioned:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ (excellent tutorial for beginners)
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
3. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html
4. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 1):

I might do this like this. I'd try to avoid `notify`/`notifyAll` as you'll have to involve a flag because of spurious wakeups and that clutters the code quite a bit. `CountDownLatch` is a much better choice here IMO even though the name is a bit weird.

```
static final long five_sec = TimeUnit.SECOND.toNanos(5)
final Queue<Pair<Guest, CountDownLatch>> guests = new LinkedList<>();
long earliest = -1;

// Synchronizing on "this" is fine but using private lock 
// object is even better
final Object lock = new Object();


void enter(Guest g){
    Pair p = Pair.of(g, new CountDownLatch(1));
    synchronized(lock){
        guests.get().add(p);
        earliest = System.nanoTime() + five_sec;
    }
    p.second.await();
}

void pickGuests(){
    synchronized(lock){
        // pop a few guests from sofar and wake them
        Guest g = sofar.poll();
        if(g != null){
            g.second.countDown();
        }
    }

}

void run(){
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        long sleepTime;
        synchronized(lock){
            if(System.nanoTime() > earliest){
                pickGuests();
            }
            sleepTime = earliest - System.nanoTime();
            sleepTime = sleepTime < five_sec ? five_sec : sleepTime;
        }
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    }
}
```